# Trouble with else not executing

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

I'm having trouble with my if statement not working 100%.

When the criteria for the if statement = true then everything works out fine,
but when the criteria doesn't = true the else part does not execute.

This is my 3rd day in trying to  develop in C#, so I don't know if I'm just doing it all wrong... and if I'm busy being a noob, suggestions on improving this code would be highly appreciated.

So please help with the if statement and improving the code ?

```
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SCIENTIFICFS;Initial Catalog=TL_ScientificInstruments;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Reports;Password=Reports"))
        {
            sqlConnection2.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From tbl_ScientificEng_Product_Info Where Syspro_StockCode = '" + product.Trim() + "'", sqlConnection2))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader2;
                reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader2.Read()) {
                    if (reader2.HasRows)
                    {
                        textBox4.Text = reader2.GetString(0);
                        textBox5.Text = reader2.GetString(1);
                        textBox6.Text = reader2.GetString(2);
                        textBox7.Text = reader2.GetString(3);
                        textBox8.Text = reader2.GetString(4);
                        textBox9.Text = reader2.GetString(5);
                        textBox10.Text = reader2.GetString(6);

                        label19.Visible = true;
                        label10.Visible = false;

                        textBox11.Enabled = false;
                        textBox12.Enabled = false;
                        textBox13.Enabled = false;
                        textBox14.Enabled = false;
                        textBox15.Enabled = false;
                        textBox16.Enabled = false;
                        textBox17.Enabled = false;

                        button2.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        MessageBox.Show("In Else Statement");
                        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select top 1 * from tbl_ScientificEng_Product_Info Where Syspro_StockCode like Left('" + product.Trim() + "%',7)", sqlConnection2)) {
                            SqlDataReader reader3;
                            reader3 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader3.Read()) {
                                textBox4.Text = reader3.GetString(0);
                                textBox5.Text = reader3.GetString(1);
                                textBox6.Text = reader3.GetString(2);
                                textBox7.Text = reader3.GetString(3);
                                textBox8.Text = reader3.GetString(4);
                                textBox9.Text = reader3.GetString(5);
                                textBox10.Text = reader3.GetString(6);

                                label19.Visible = false;
                                label10.Visible = true;
                            }
                            //reader3.Close();
                        }
                        //reader2.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What path does it take if you break there and follow it through in the debugger?

Comment: Have you debugged through your code and examined the local variables?

Comment: I would guess that `reader2.Read()` returns `true` only if `reader2.HasRows` is `true`, so instead of hitting the `else,` the loop has exited.

Comment: Have you walked through it with the debugger?  If so, then what does it do.  If not, then you need to do that.

Comment: Get the habit of reading the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx). Seems to me that if there are no rows then control drops out of the `while` - the `else` can't execute.

Comment: I think you need to change Left('" + product.Trim() + "%',7)" to using product.Trim().Substring(0,7)+"%"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that the `else` isn't executing, it's that when there are no rows you never enter the loop in the first place.  Take a look at what you're doing here:

```
while (reader2.Read()) {
    if (reader2.HasRows) {
```

If the reader has no rows, then `Read()` is going to return `false`.  So the `while` loop is never entered, and the `if/else` becomes a moot point because it'll never be evaluated.

Normally you would check `.HasRows` *before* trying to read those rows in the loop.  Something like this:

```
if (reader2.HasRows)
{
    while (reader2.Read())
    {
        // the contents of your "if" block
    }
}
else
{
    // the contents of your "else" block
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Might have some code in the wrong order, try:

```
if(reader2.HasRows)
{
    while(reader2.Read())
    {
        //code
    }
}
```